# TSQLT - Error while trying to fake a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsqlt

Hi I am pretty new for TSQLT Unit tests I am getting error while trying to create a fake table, any help is appreciated.

I have my dev project in one database and TSQLT in another database

```
EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable @TableName = '[AnotherDB].[dbo].[Table1]'
```

The error is

```
[Test].[test that checks the size] failed: (Error) FakeTable could not resolve the object name, '[AnotherDB].[dbo].[Table1]'. (When calling tSQLt.FakeTable, avoid the use of the @SchemaName parameter, as it is deprecated.)[16,10]{Private_ValidateFakeTableParameters,12}
```

Although this table does exist in another database, select * will work on this table. Also
I have seen couple of posts but not clear what to do.

Comment: With the information given, how do you think people can help you???

Comment: is using synonyms for table in another database - an option?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev good shout, thanks, let me try this

Comment: That's not all :) tSQLt doesn't work with such synonyms as well (yet). But you can use my Pull Request for that. https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/pull/48 I hope it will be merged one day. Sebastian seems to be very busy by integrating tSQLt into github CI

Comment: About to write you back on an error by using synonymns :)  I will be waiting for your feature to be merged,  although using synonyms gave me error - An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure 'sp_addextendedproperty

Comment: I'm waiting for that for half of year already. Good luck. By the way, it is quite well covered by tests.

Comment: oh that is too much :), I saw your PR, guess If I have to make the changes then in TSQLT tables and SP's directly to use synonyms where or which commit should I start with

Comment: I don't have that database locally right now. Will try to setup the tSQLt project from sources and create schema scripts today later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FakeTable cannot (yet) resolve objects in another database.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native functionality yet for that, however I've created pull request in the [tSQLt github repository](https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/pull/48) that implements that feature. You can build the project by yourself, or you can use pre-build dacpac from [my repo](https://github.com/dkultasev/SSDTPowerTemplate/tree/master/dacpac). In that dacpac you'll find official `tSQLt` objects + 2 my features (faking synonyms and improved way to fake the functions). You can check for fake function examples [here](https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/pull/53)

So, for your case, you need to create the synonym for that object and then mock it with the `FakeTable` in the same way you do for tables.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look